# Virtualenv and django interaction

Tags: django, virtualenv

I installed Django 2.1.3 in my windows computer for project then created a virtualenv for another django project, So after activating virtualenv.

I nothing installed in my virtualenv yet, so why I am able to run the command django-admin startproject without installing django.

But when I try to runserver in virtualenv by command:

```
manage.py runserver
```

I get the error, i.e django is not installed in virtualenv

Need some explanation why is happening in my virtualenv

Comment: Hi @Bhupendra, Its because you installed Django globally in your system and not inside the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

> so why I am able to run the command django-admin startproject without
>   installing django

That is because `django-admin` is in your system's `PATH` so it can run in any virtual environment or outside. Starting a django project and creating an environment for it are two different things. Meaning you can create a project outside environments using `django-admin` and then use an existing environment to work on that project or create a new environment specifically for that project. So just install Django in your new `venv`.

And be careful with using `django-admin` as it uses the system's django version therefore after installing Django in your `venv`, just use `python manage.py`

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You can run django commands because you installed it in your computer and it's using that installation.

**Second:** Because you need to install Django in your Virtualenv too. The virtualenv is a environment that is separeted of your computer so you need to install all the dependencies that you want to have in your virtual environment. All the dependencies that you have in this environment isn't in your pc and viceversa.

That allow you to have different versions in your computer and in your virtual environment and different dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating another virtualenv for the first project with the correct requirements, and then removing the system version of Django.  That will be cleaner for the future.